# Change IP identifier of an Android phone

Tags: applications, internet

There's a social media app that I had installed on two Android phones. For a reason I cannot explain, one phone was "banned" from using the app. I contacted customer service but with no reply. No matter what account I use to log in, if I sign up for a new account, or reinstall the app, the app says my account was suspended. On the second phone, everything works ok. They are both connected to the same WiFi, so clearly they are banning some identifiers of the phone.

My question is, is there a way around this? I can already join using one phone, but it's an old and slow one. There must be some hack to change the IP viewed by the app. By the way, I'm not doing anything illegal, I'm just an IT amateur enthusiast.

Comment: They probably aren't using your IP address, because that tends to change quite often. There are a lot of different unique and stable IDs that they could be using, including advertising identifiers, serial numbers, MAC addresses, IMEI or ICCID numbers, and more. Without knowing what they're using, it's hard to know how to help you. Do both phones have SIM cards? If you swap SIM cards, does the problem follow the SIM card, or the phone? Have you tried resetting the Advertising ID? Have you tried wiping the phone and setting it up from scratch?

Comment: If it is an old phone then most likely they use the ANDROID_ID. This id is persistent and is generated on first boot. On a non-rooted device you ca only do a factory reset to change the ANDROID_ID.

Comment: In case this is an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/241919), mentioning the name of the app may help in determining which identifiers are actually used.

Comment: @ Robert, clearing GSF data had a similar effect [way back](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1r1n5z/comment/cdiymrp/) // not sure if that's the case subsequently